# Track privacy guarantees in a federated learning process with DP-query

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I'm a bit new to TFF, I have checked github and followed the EMNIST example to train a differentially private federated model using `DP-FedAvg` algorithm. Mainly this is done by attaching a `dp-query` to the `aggregation_process` then train the federated model.

I have a question please:

**1. Given that attaching a `dp-query` to the aggregation process would result in a participant-level Central-DP ,  How would I track the privacy guarantee (eps, delta) during training ?**

below is a code snippet where a differentially private federated model is set up with 100 participants, that is why both `expected_total_weight` and `expected_clients_per_round` are set to 100

```
def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        keras_model=keras_model,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        input_spec=preprocessed_first_client_dataset.element_spec,
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])


dp_query = tff.utils.build_dp_query(
    clip=1.0,
    noise_multiplier=0.3,
    expected_total_weight=100,
    adaptive_clip_learning_rate=0,
    target_unclipped_quantile=0.5,
    clipped_count_budget_allocation=0.1,
    expected_clients_per_round=100
)


weights_type = tff.learning.framework.weights_type_from_model(model_fn)

aggregation_process = tff.utils.build_dp_aggregate_process(weights_type.trainable, dp_query)

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(0.1),
    server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0),
    aggregation_process=aggregation_process
)
```

I came across several methods to compute epsilon and delta in TF-Privacy, but it seems they are meant to track privacy guarantee of the traditional `DP-SGD` algorithm and expect to receive parameters such as `steps`,  `n` and `batch_size`

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: but it shows that tff has no attribute utils now any suggestions on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to perform this calculation. We will discuss two options below.

### Re-purposing DPSGD analysis tools

You are correct that these tools accept parameters which are named for the DP-SGD setting; however, their arguments can be remapped to the federated setting in a fairly straightforward manner.

Suppose we have the symbol `apply_dp_sgd_analysis` from [TFP's analysis library](https://github.com/tensorflow/privacy/blob/master/tensorflow_privacy/privacy/analysis/compute_dp_sgd_privacy_lib.py). We can write a simple function that essentially modifies the body of `compute_dp_sgd_privacy` for the federated setting:

```py
def compute_fl_privacy(num_rounds, noise_multiplier, num_users, users_per_round):
  # This actually assumes Poisson subsampling, which may not be *quite*
  # right in your setting, but the approximation should be close either way.
  q = users_per_round / num_users  # q - the sampling ratio.

  # These orders are inlined from the body of compute_dp_sgd_privacy
  orders = ([1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2., 2.25, 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5] +
            list(range(5, 64)) + [128, 256, 512])
  
  # Depending on whether your TFF code by default uses adaptive clipping or not,
  # you may need to rescale your noise_multiplier argument.

  return apply_dp_sgd_analysis(
    q, sigma=noise_multiplier, steps=num_rounds, orders=orders, delta=num_users ** (-1))
```

### Using TFP PrivacyLedger

If you're using the relatively new [`tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/aggregators/DifferentiallyPrivateFactory?version=nightly) (which I would suggest over the DP process used above), you can pass an already-constructed `DPQuery`, which can be decorated with a [`PrivacyLedger`](https://github.com/tensorflow/privacy/blob/a579cc4afcfa0420fef37841aedf91d22b3eef48/tensorflow_privacy/privacy/analysis/privacy_ledger.py#L53). This ledger could then be passed directly into a function like [`compute_rdp_from_ledger`](https://github.com/tensorflow/privacy/blob/a579cc4afcfa0420fef37841aedf91d22b3eef48/tensorflow_privacy/privacy/analysis/rdp_accountant.py#L300), and it should have tracked the privacy spent from each of the query calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, much appreciated,

I'm trying to use the ```DifferentialPrivateFactory``` to apply the ```dp-query```, but I'm stuck with the ```value_type```, not sure what is the proper type to put there, 

code sample is in the next comment,

appreciate your advice,

Comment: ```factory = dp_factory.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory(dp_query)```


```value_type = computation_types.TensorType(dtype=tf.float32)```


```aggregation_process = factory.create(value_type)```

        
 ```iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
model_fn=model_fn,
client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(LR),
server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(S_LR),
aggregation_process=aggregation_process
)```

Comment: The keras model in ```model_fn``` is below
:
```tf.keras.Sequential([
layers.Reshape((28, 28, 1), input_shape=(784,)),

layers.Conv2D(16, 8, strides=2, padding='same',activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),

layers.MaxPool2D(2, 1),

layers.Conv2D(32, 4,strides=2,padding='valid', activation='relu'),

layers.MaxPool2D(2, 1),

layers.Dropout(0.2),

layers.Flatten(),

layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),

tayers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')])```

Comment: Note: with the new work on `tff.aggregators` included in the just released TFF [`0.18.0`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/releases/tag/v0.18.0) a simple way to construct a DP aggregator for learning tasks is with is with [`tff.learning.dp_aggregator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/dp_aggregator) and a general-purpose way to wrap an arbitrary `DPQuery` from `tensorflow-privacy` for use in TFF is via [`tff.aggregators.DifferentiallyPrivateFactory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/aggregators/DifferentiallyPrivateFactory).